# I only need to bind to my element one time, with JQuery's Live

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In MVC3, I have a view _Foo:

I have a AJAX success callback, where I render a html tabel. That part works.

Because the table is created inside the ajax.success I have to use `live` to listen on event on the tablerows.

I do this with:

```
$("#FooTable tbody tr").live('click', 
                        function(evt) { checkOrUnCheckCheckbox(evt, $(this)); });
```

The `checkOrUnCheckCheckbox` callback sets the checkbox in the last column in the selected row.

**Here's the problem:** But then when the dialog is loaded another time `live` is binded to the table. So now I have the same bind two times, and the checkbox is being set AND unset everytime. And likewise if I open the dialog again its calls three times, and its "works", but still I don't want the function `checkOrUnCheckCheckbox` to be called multiple times.

Is the solution, to somehow first ask if it's bind and then not bind it again with live or what?

**EDIT**: More code shared, for better understanding.

```
// document.ready and the binding
$(document).ready(function () {
    initializeDefaults();
    // use live to bind table, because the table is created in a ajax callback.
    $("#ModtagereTable tbody tr").live('click', 
        function(evt) { checkMedtag(evt, $(this)); });
    });
});

// init. Load of tabel
function initializeDefaults() {
   loadModtagerGruppe();
};

//ajax call to get the list and populate the table with it in the ajax callback           
function loadModtagerGruppe() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Foo/GetModtagerListe/',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        })
        .success(function (result) {
            if (result && result.error) {
                //Display error message
                return;
            }

            if (result != null) {
                var tbody = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var item = result[i];

                    tbody = tbody + '<tr class="modtagerRow"><td>' + 
                                      item.FirmaNavn + '</td>' +
                                '<td>' + item.Telefon + '</td>';

                    // Checkbox
                    tbody = tbody + '<td><input type="checkbox"></td>' 
                    + '</tr>';

                }
                $('#ModtagereTable tbody').html(tbody);

            }
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
            //Remove spinner
            $('#ModtagereTable tbody').html("");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: which is the jquery version used

Comment: Looks like you don't need to use live() at all because obviously you are binding event once element is created, so then, just replace `live` with `bind` (or `on`). If you delegate event, don't bind it in 'onload' event of dialog.

Comment: I have tryed every solution mutilple times now, and they all sound good but it still doesn't work for me. Maybe I am missing something. I think I have to reproduce a running sample and open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `live` it's deprecated. Use `on` with a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$('#FooTable').on('click', 'tr', checkOrUnCheckCheckbox);

function checkOrUnCheckCheckbox(event) {
    var el = this;
    // your check/uncheck logic...
}
```

Note that you will need to upgrade jQuery to at least version 1.7, but you should be using this as a minimum already

Comment: how does it remove the previously added handler.... don't we have to use `off()`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny i guess you are correct, now just wondering why OP was using `live()`

Comment: It made no difference. checkOrUnCheckCheckbox() is still being called two times in one click, the second time i open the dialog.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan where should i place `$('#FooTable').on('click', 'tr', checkOrUnCheckCheckbox);` ? I have it in document.ready now, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`live()` is deprecated and removed, you should be using `on()`, and to bind only once, `one()`

```
$(document).one('click', "#FooTable tbody tr", function(evt) { 
     checkOrUnCheckCheckbox(evt, $(this)); 
});
```

replace `document` with closest non-dynamic parent.

It does sound like you should be using `on()`

```
$(document).on('click', "#FooTable tbody tr", function(evt) { 
     checkOrUnCheckCheckbox(evt, $(this)); 
});
```

but do the binding outside any callback from the ajax function so it's only done once, it will apply to any elements you insert later.

Comment: don't think `one` is the solution because what if tr is clicked twice in the same dialog

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I don't think one() is the solution either, just added it as the title says "bind once", but I'm guessing the real issue is placing a delegated event handler inside a callback function that is executed multiple times.

Comment: yes... there is only one problem if the script is loaded as part of the dynamic html like in a `load()` request... else OP need to move the script registration code to dom ready handler

Comment: @adeneo It works now. I changed it to `on` and moved my binding from document.ready to the ajax callback. BUT, you said I should move it outside the ajax binding, but I moved in inside. I believe in you, so now I am confused, can you help me more?

Comment: Yes, this is delegated to the document right now, so it shouldn't be inside the ajax callback, place it outside and it should work just as well, and the document is always available so it doesn't really have to be inside document.ready either.

Answer (score 1):

If you don've have a new version of jQuery and wants to continue using live()

```
function handler() {
    checkOrUnCheckCheckbox(evt, $(this));
}
$("#FooTable tbody tr").die('click', handler).live('click', handler);
```

Comment: die didnt help. I still get the function to be called twice, with one click. Maybe I should edit a code sample.

Comment: @radbyx you should share more context to the problem